# Join elements of two lists in Python

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have two **Python** lists containing strings that may or may not be of the same length.

```
list1 = ['a','b']
list2 = ['c','d','e']
```

I want to get the following result:

```
l = ['a c','a d','a e','b c','b d','b e']
```

The final list all possible combinations from the two lists with a space in between them.

One method I've tried is with `itertools`

```
import itertools
for p in itertools.permutations(, 2):
     print(zip(*p))
```

But unfortunately this was not what I needed, as it did not return any combinations at all.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: l=[f'{c1} {c2}' for c1 in list1 for c2 in list2 ]

Answer (score 1):

First make all possible combinations of the two lists, then use list comprehension to achieve the desired result:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b']
list2 = ['c', 'd', 'e']


com = [(x,y) for x in list1 for y in list2]
print([a + ' ' + b for (a, b) in com]) # ['a c', 'a d', 'a e', 'b c', 'b d', 'b e']
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a cartesian product.

Code:

```
import itertools

list1 = ['a', 'b']
list2 = ['c', 'd', 'e']

l = ['%s %s' % (e[0], e[1]) for e in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
print(l)
```

result:

```
['a c', 'a d', 'a e', 'b c', 'b d', 'b e']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another possible method:

```
list1=['a','b']
list2=['c','d','e']
list3=[]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        list3.append(i+" "+j)
print(list3)
```

Answer (score 0):

One-Liner Solution, Use list comprehension and add the items of list

```
list1 = ['a','b']
list2 = ['c','d','e']
print([i+j for i in list1 for j in list2])
```